# About Adding Lines to Your startup.m file

Tags: matlab, installation, startup, toolbox

I'm trying to add specific lines to my startup.m file to install a specific toolbox using MATLAB. However, I'm not able to find any startup.m file.

How can I add lines to my startup.m file? I'm a Mac user.

Answer (score 0):

Type `edit startup` in MATLAB. This will create a `startup.m` file in the current directory, if it doesn't exist anywhere on your path yet, and open it in the MATLAB Editor.

Do this while in the default directory (i.e. the directory where MATLAB starts up in), so that your new `startup.m` file is found every time MATLAB starts.